# Inserting Embedded Style Sheets into my HTML code causes webpage not be displayed?

Tags: html, css

I've just started learning coding and HTML for the 1st time and have run into some issues when learning the CSS portion. I've used a CSS validator and it hasn't found any issues, yet when I try to load my page in firefox, all I get is a blank white screen. I'm using notepad++ as my editor.
I suspect it might be a formatting issue but have been unable to find exactly where's the error. Would appreciate any help on my code below. THanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <style type="text/css”>     
        body{font-family:Calibri;         
            color:darkblue;         
            background-color:lightcyan
            }     
        h2 {color:brown;         
           font-family:verdana;         
           font-style:italic
           } 
 </style>
</head>

<body> 
    <h1> This is my HTML Page</h1>     
    <h2> Nothing new here</h2>     
    <p>This page is written <span style="color:red">normally</span> as any other HTML page. It will display either in default font, color, size attributes or in customised fashion  depending on whether the <b>head</b> section contains a style or not</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css”> // the second quotation is not correct change it to this " not ”
```

Answer (score 3):

Change U+201D of the `type` attribute of the `style` element to U+0022.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- type="text/css” to type="text/css" -->
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Calibri;
      color: darkblue;
      background-color: lightcyan
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: brown;
      font-family: verdana;
      font-style: italic
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> This is my HTML Page</h1>
  <h2> Nothing new here</h2>
  <p>This page is written <span style="color:red">normally</span> as any other HTML page. It will display either in default font, color, size attributes or in customised fashion depending on whether the <b>head</b> section contains a style or not</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To phrase it a little simpler: in your line `<style type="text/css”> ` the double-quotes are of litographic type. That is not permitted and could come from using a wrong text editor.

Comment: @EagleRainbow I guessed the comment text and fixed the comment out position. Is this what you expected? Also, please tell me what the "litographic type" mean, if you possible.

Comment: This was more a comment to @thebulk. To me it appears that (s)he might not be experienced with computer science yet, that is why I tried to find a simpler explanation. 
With "litographic type" I mean that UTF-8 knows multiple types of double-quotes. There are the "normal double quotes" which we typically use (`"´) and there are - for instance - those which have been used in printing in former times. Often they are considered to look "nicer". That is also why e.g. MS Word has a corresponding auto-replacement activated which may spoil thing for you (as in this case here).

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the double quotes. Corrected code is as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">     
  body{font-family:Calibri;         
   color:darkblue;         
   background-color:lightcyan
   }     
  h2 {color:brown;         
     font-family:verdana;         
     font-style:italic
     } 
 </style>
</head>
 
<body> 
 <h1> This is my HTML Page</h1>     
 <h2> Nothing new here</h2>     
 <p>This page is written <span style="color:red; "> normally</span> as any other HTML page. It will display either in default font, color, size attributes or in customised fashion  depending on whether the <b>head</b> section contains a style or not</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Please try this.